# How to display differences between 2 complex Objects in Angular 7 with different color?

Tags: javascript, angular, object, angular7

I am listing objects with `*ngFor` and `*ngFor|keyvalue` which I get them as an `Array` from `MongoDB`. On the left side of the view I am listing `newVersion (new results)` and on the right side I am listing `previous results`.

Is there possibility someone to advise me about best practice, how to show what have changed object?

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use `[ngClass]` or `[ngStyle]` feature of angular.

```
E.x: [ngClass]="{'active':obj == 'value'}"

E.x: [ngStyle]="{'pointer-events': obj.flag == 1 ? 'none' : 'visible' }"
```

This way you can apply your css or class.

Comment: How do  I detect the changes ?

Comment: As I gave e.x in ans. Like flag value. based on that angular will apply class or css.